# How do I draw 2 lines with 2 different colors: each set of lines has set Coordinates. the Sets are not connected

Tags: mkpolyline, cllocationcoordinate2d

How do I draw two lines not connected to each other, the two lines must have to different colors, the two lines have points from four set of coordinates. So each line has its own set of coordinates. Using Objective C iOS 7.

Tower Two does not draw right now

```
 if ([deg2 isEqual: @""] ) {
    //nil

}else{
    //not nil

    //Tower Two
    //draw line from lat2/long2 to finalLat2/finalLong2
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray2[2];
    coordinateArray2[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat2 doubleValue], [long2 doubleValue]); //tower two
    coordinateArray2[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(finalLat2, finalLong2);
    self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray2 count:2];

}
```

Tower One does draw

```
   //tower one
  // [self.mapview setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]]; //If you want the route to be visible
    //draw line from lat1/long1 to finalLat1/finalLong1
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[2];
    coordinateArray[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat1 doubleValue], [long1     doubleValue]); //tower one
    coordinateArray[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(finalLat1, finalLong1);



    self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
    [self.mapview setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]]; //If you want the route to be visible
    [self.mapview addOverlay:self.routeLine];
}
```

Here is how Tower One gets the line color

```
//Tower One Line
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if(overlay == self.routeLine)
    {
        if(nil == self.routeLineView)
        {
            self.routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
            self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 5;
        }
        return self.routeLineView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add in the .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolyline *routeLine1; //ORGINAL LINE
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolylineView *routeLineView1; //ORGINAL LINE

@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolyline *routeLine2; //ADDED LINE
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolylineView *routeLineView2; //ADDED LINE
```

This in the .m

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
if(overlay == self.routeLine1)
{
    if(nil == self.routeLineView1)
    {
        self.routeLineView1 = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine1];
        self.routeLineView1.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        self.routeLineView1.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        self.routeLineView1.lineWidth = 5;

    }

    return self.routeLineView1;
}


if(overlay == self.routeLine2)
{
    if(nil == self.routeLineView2)
    {
        self.routeLineView2 = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine2];
        self.routeLineView2.fillColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        self.routeLineView2.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        self.routeLineView2.lineWidth = 5;

    }

    return self.routeLineView2;
}

return nil;

}
```